# JavaScript: Replace month numbers with month name in json

Tags: javascript, json

I have json data for few months with month values eq. "2015-01", "2015-04"........ and I want to convert all the numeric values to "JAN", "FEB" .... according to months respectively by any javascript function. Below is actual array object and required(I needed) array object.

```
var ActualData = [
    {"month" : "2015-01", "val" : 230.67},
    {"month" : "2015-04", "val" : 345.87},
    {"month" : "2015-08", "val" : 455.78}
];

var monthsName = ["JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG","SEP","OCT","NOV","DEC"];

var ExpectedData = [
    {"month" : "JAN", "val" : 230.67},
    {"month" : "APR", "val" : 345.87},
    {"month" : "AUG", "val" : 455.78}
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map over the array, get the month number from the string and then return the modified object.

```
var ExpectedData = ActualData.map(function(obj) {
    // Get month number from date-string and then substract 1
    var monthNum = parseInt(obj.month.slice(-2)) - 1;
    // Get month name from the array
    obj.month = monthsName[monthNum];
    // Return the object
    return obj;
});
```

Comment: I liked this technique, just would like to concat "2015" with the desired month name. eq. "2015 JAN".

Answer (score 2):

Use `Array.prototype.map`:

```
var ExpectedData = ActualData.map(function(item){
  return {
    month: monthsName[parseInt(item.month.split('-')[1], 10) -1],
    val: item.val

  };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Something along these lines should work:

```
    var monName = monthsName[parseInt(ActualData[i].month.substring(ActualData[i].month.indexOf('-') + 1), 10) - 1]
```

If you are looking to construct ExpectedData then you could use this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < ActualData.length; i++)
{
    ExpectedData.push('month': monthsName[parseInt(ActualData[i].month.substring(ActualData[i].month.indexOf('-') + 1), 10) - 1], 'val': ActualData[i].val);
}
```

Note:  This is not very elegant but it gets the job done.